# django is_user in view

Tags: django

I am trying to generate a list of sites based on the user that is logged in. If the User is_staff, they get all sites, If not they get the sites that belong to the same company as the user.

The view never returns with is_staff = True. Even when they are.

models.py

```
class Site(models.Model):
    site_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.site_name


class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False)

    users = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    sites = models.ManyToManyField(Site)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

views.py

```
class SiteList(ListView):
    model = Company
    paginate_by = 25

    def get_queryset(self):
        if self.request.user.is_staff:
            return Company.objects.all()

        else:
            user = User.objects.get(id=self.request.user.id)
            return Company.objects.filter(users=user.id)
```

company_list.html:

```
{% for company in company_list %}
   {% for s in company.sites.all %}
        {{ s.site_name }}
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Maybe it's `Company_objects.filter(users__id=user.id)`?

Comment: That is the way I originally did it. Still same result

Comment: Also, you have to make sure that `company_list` is the right variable name in template. Django template won't give you error if you use a wrong variable name.

Comment: You don't need to use `user = User.objects.get(id=self.request.user.id)`. Just use `self.request.user`.

Comment: What do you get if you print/log the user in your `get_queryset` method, e.g. `print(self.request.user)` or `print(self.request.user.is_staff)`?